# Motivation of considering $\frac{\chi(n)}{(mn)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ when proving the non-vanishing of $L(\chi, 1)$.

Tags: analytic-number-theory

In Stein’s *Fourier Analysis: an introduction*, Dirichlet’s hyperbola method is introduced, which serves as a key step to prove Dirichlet’s theorem on arithmetic progressions. For a real, nontrivial character, define a function $F(m,n)=\frac{\chi(n)}{(mn)^\frac{1}{2}}$, and the sum $S_N=\sum_{mn\leq N}F(m,n)$. Applying Dirichlet’s hyperbola method, we obtain the following results:
i) $S_N \geq c \log{N}$ for some $c>0$;
ii)$S_N=2N^{1/2}L(\chi,1)+O(1)$, and the non-vanishing of L-function follows.

I wonder the motivation of defining $F(m,n)$ for the summation along hyperbolas. Does it involve some deeper results?

Comment: As stated, the factor $m^{-1/2}$ can be completely factored out of both $F(m,n)$ and $S_N$. Are you sure those formulas are correct?

Comment: It is $S_N=\sum_{mn\le N} \chi(m)m^{-1/2} n^{-1/2}$. It works the same way for $\sum_{mn\le N} \chi(m)m^{-1/2+a} n^{-1/2+a}$ with $a\in [0,1/2)$

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in the statement.

Comment: But why we need to consider this $\chi(m)m^{-\frac{1}{2}}n^{-\frac{1}{2}}$?